# Bokeh polar projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, bokeh

Does anyone know how to plot a polar graph using Bokeh?
I am trying to show received signal data and i need to project it as a polar graph.
I've try to google and find a solution but I couldn't find a solution regarding this. 
Anyone has a solution for this?

[image: Polar Sample graph]

Comment: Similar to [this one](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/burtin.html)? If you show an image with some example would help to find the solution

Comment: @ChesuCR Thanks. I've added the sample image to the question.

Comment: I'm also very interested in the answer to this. With ggplot2 you can use the coor_polar argument, but I haven't been able to find anything similar in bokeh. Seaborn does have a projection='polar' option (https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/facet_projections.html).